# Missing properties of Kinect V1 Matlab 2017a - no TrackingMode

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, kinect

I have some troubles connecting Kinect V1 with Matlab 2017a. I use all codes in Matlab 2013a and works perfectly. But in Matlab 2017a some properties are missing. There is no "TrackingMode", "BodyPosture", "DepthMode", "IREmitter" and "SkeletonsToTrack".

[exemple in Matlab tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvldo.png)

.
.
.

[the image of what i have got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmxXY.png)

.
.
.

My code:

```
%Testes iniciais para Kinect no Matlab 2017
clear all;
close all;
clc;
vid = videoinput('kinect',1,'RGB_640x480')
src = getselectedsource(vid)
src.BacklightCompensation = 'LowLightsPriority';
preview(vid);
pause();
closepreview(vid);
vid2 = videoinput('kinect',2,'Depth_640x480');
src = getselectedsource(vid2);
start(vid2);
% Get the data on the object.
[frame, ts, metaData] = getdata(vid2);
% Look at the metadata to see the parameters in the skeletal data.
metaData
metaData.IsSkeletonTracked
metaData.JointWorldCoordinates(:,:,1)
% View the segmentation data as an image.
imagesc(metaDataDepth.SegmentationData);
% Set the color map to jet to color code the people detected.
colormap(jet);
```

.
.
.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Are you using MATLAB R2017a on Windows OS? Are you using [*ℎ *](https://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/kinect-windows.html) ?

Comment: I am using Windows 7. I use this command to verify the package:

>> matlabshared.supportpkg.getInstalled
                                 Name                                   Version       Base Product       
----------------------------------------------------------------------- ------- -------------------------
Image Acquisition Toolbox Support Package for Kinect for Windows Sensor 17.1.0  Image Acquisition Toolbox

Comment: The skeleton is not working

Comment: @Sardar Usama Do you help any ideas to help me? I will be very thankfull

Comment: Do you see those properties in 'Kinect Explorer'?

Comment: Please add the link to the documentation/tutorial where you read that. Please don't add text as an image. Add text as text. Also please write everything in your post in English (referring to the first comment in your code)

Comment: I am already using the kinect in Matlab 2013a. I can see the the four icons in the "Device Manager" on Windows 7. Sorry the mistakes. I do not understand what you mean by "Kinect Explorer". Do you mean the "Microsoft Developer Toolkit" ? I just can not use in Matlab 2017a

Comment: There will be an application named 'Kinect Explorer'. You have R2013a and R2017a on the same system?

Comment: Yes. But I tried with just the R2017a installed and do not work too

Comment: I was doing my work in R2013a very well. But I see that that Neural Networks Toolbox in R2017a is much better

Comment: I have no idea how that's relevant. Btw you haven't fixed the content of your post as I pointed out earlier (about text as text and in English)

Comment: My biggest problem is not the post. My biggest problem is that kinect do not work in R2017a. (It was just one setence in the code in portuguese)

Comment: the text is added as an image..... please read the comment again and fix your post accordingly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102346/missing-properties-of-kinect-v1-matlab-2017a-no-trackingmode#comment79233196_46102346

Comment: I will fix in the next posts. Is it real relevant for that questions?

Comment: If you're less interested in fixing your post, we would rather be less interested in looking for your solution

Comment: If I fix my post, then you will be able to help me?

Comment: Thanks a lot, "Mr. -2 points for you"

Comment: i didn't give you any negative points

Comment: Ops, seems like I am beeing realy dumb today. Sorry